# jQuery closest() question

Tags: jquery, closest

To all: sorry if I've not understood the protocol here at StackOverflow. I will immediately endeavor to correct my standing within the community. Having said that:

I'm trying to change the context of a jQuery function depending upon what calls it. In the following code, when the page first loads, we see that the limitDates() function is called with HTMLElementDiv as the current context. When we call it by typing in the input field, we see that it's not a div, but trying to get the parent div using $(this).closest('div') returns an HTMLElementInput, not the div. Any thoughts?

update: have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/earachefl/XBFNQ/8/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="common/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" ></script>

<div class="datemodule">
    <input class="date_from" type="text" id="date_from_#name#" name="date_from" value=#start#>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.datemodule').limitDates();
        $('.date_from').keydown(function(){
            $(this).limitDates();
        });
    });

    (function($){
        $.fn.limitDates = function(){                   
            return this.each(function(){
                context = $(this).context;
                //alert(context);
                alert(context.nodeName);
                if (context.nodeName != 'DIV'){
                    alert('not a div');
                    newContext = $(this).closest('div').context;
                    alert(newContext.nodeName);
                }
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Just to give you an idea, I opened the question, saw 0%, and immediately stopped reading. When I finish this, I will click back to the main page and not give this question a second thought.

Comment: Sorry guys, didn't understand the protocol here. I'll attempt to be a better citizen. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is the DOM element that is passed to JQuery(). So your selectors in the first place have both the context as document.

```
$('div.datemodule').limitDates(); // context is the document
$('.date_from').keydown(...   // context is the document
```

When it comes to a callback, if you use $(this) context is the element that triggers the event.

```
$('.date_from').keydown(function(){
    $(this).limitDates();         // context is the element which has class .date_form and triggered that event
});
```

And when it comes to your function where you use this.each the context is set to each element in each iteration.

```
return this.each(function(){
    $(this).context; // context is the element of iteration
}
```

As i said context is what is passed to JQuery and probably it is readonly.

Comment: So, if we're calling from $('.date_from').keydown, the context is the element which has class .date_from, and inside the function which uses this.each, there'll be only one element of iteration, which is that element with class .date_from. Right? If that's the case, at that point, why doesn't $(this).closest('div') return the parent div?

Comment: Now I'm really confused, kingjiv. When I call the function using the input element, the context is that element, got that. Therefore $(this) is a jQuery wrapper around that input element, right? Therefore, calling $(this).closest('div') should return the parent div, right?

Comment: nvm, I think I finally got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The description of context is :

> ```
> The DOM node context originally passed to jQuery();
> ```

So even after calling `closest` the context is still the original `input` passed to `jQuery`.

If you want to get the `div`, why not just get it?

```
newContext = $(this).closest('div')[0];
```

Comment: I've tried getting it... but in my fiddle, $(this).closest('div') returns an input element, not the parent div. Did you get a different result?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XBFNQ/10/  `$(this).closest('div')` returns a `div`, you are doing `$(this).closest('div').context` which is an input.

Comment: Oh... so the context remains the same for all returned elements? Now I get it. D'oh.